# divs overlaying in grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some layout, but been stuck with overlapping div - 'featured works' is like going under row with 3 icons and honestly can't figure out solution for this one. Just need to put overlapping div under three icons section. There will also be a few more under, so any advices appreciated.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* columns */

.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

... typical grid 1-12
/* offset */

.col-offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.33%;
}

... same as above
/* clearfix */

row::before,
row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* === */

header nav {
  background-color: #544B46;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.icons {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.icons i {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  color: #544B46;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px #544B46 solid;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.icons h1,
.icons p {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li><a href=”#”>About us</a></li>
          <li><a href=”#”>Mission</a></li>
          <li><a href=”#”>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://naturalnie.media.pl/test/train-long.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="icons">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <i class="fab fa-researchgate"></i>
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
          <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="featured">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h1>FEATURED WORKS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Sorry for indents, new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you set your css class `[class*="col-"]` with `height: 150px;`. Get rid of the height requirement, and it goes back into place.

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
/* columns */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}... typical grid 1-12

/* offset */
.col-offset-1 {margin-left: 8.33%;}... same as above
/* clearfix */
row::before,
row::after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
[class*="col-"] {
float: left;
min-height: 1px;
/*height: 150px;*/
padding: 10px;
}
/* === */

header nav {
background-color: #544B46;
overflow: hidden;
}

header nav ul {
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li {
display:inline-block;
}

header nav ul li a {
line-height: 50px;
display: block;
color: #fff;
padding: 0 20px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hero img {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

.icons {
margin: 50px auto;
text-align: center;
}

.icons i {
height: 75px;
width: 75px;
color: #544B46;
border-radius: 10%;
background-color:#fff;
font-size: 40px;
margin: 0 auto;
cursor: pointer;
border: 2px #544B46 solid;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 15px;
}

.icons h1,
.icons p {
padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<nav class="container">
<div class="row">
<ul>
<li><a href=”#”>About us</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”>Mission</a></li>
<li><a href=”#”>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</header>
<section class="hero">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<img src="http://naturalnie.media.pl/test/train-long.jpg">
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="icons">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
<i class="fab fa-researchgate"></i>
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
<i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
<i class="fas fa-cogs"></i>
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<section class="featured">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<h1>FEATURED WORKS</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```